# Display time interval field

Tags: input-fields, time

I am working on some forms which have certain fields inside.

One of these fields is a time period for a notification function: Before/After a certain date, user should be notified every 3 days for instance.

The only thing the user may fill is the value (e.g. 3) of days for each notification.

I am wondering how may I display the fact that the number represents days, as I'm forced to have an interface with a label with text, and below the input field.

If I could change the display, I would do something like "Before event, notify every _ days", where _ is the input field. However I can only change the label that is before.

Do you have any idea to display this information with one line of text ?

If this helps, there is also a checkbox where user can specify wether he wants a recurrent notification (every 3 days) or just one (3 days before the event)

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you're looking for the best descriptive text for this situation since you're locked into a certain form layout. I suggest:

Number of days before event to send notification: [input]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question is "how do I display the number of days that the user will be notified of a certain thing?" If that's right, one line is enough but it's confusing. Each notification will have its own date since you won't send more than one per day, and you might even make it a datetime.

The reason to separate each one is to distinctly show that the number of notifications is unique and users should be highly aware of that. I'd go so far as to break it out into the text field where when you enter the number, the number of datetime lines updates dynamically.

Comment: There are only two intervals to fill, the interval before event and after event.